# cv::cudacodec::VideoReader unable to Play rtsp stream

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

**System information**

- OpenCV => 3.3.0
- Operating System / Platform => Ubuntu 16.04, x86_64
- Compiler => gcc version 5.4.1 20160904
- Cuda => 8.0
- Nvidia card => GTX 1080 Ti
- ffmpeg details

  - libavutil      55. 74.100 / 55. 74.100
  - libavcodec     57.103.100 / 57.103.100
  - libavformat    57. 77.100 / 57. 77.100
  - libavdevice    57.  7.101 / 57.  7.101
  - libavfilter     6.100.100 /  6.100.100
  - libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  - libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100

**Detailed description**

i am trying to play a rtsp stream using `cudacodec::VideoReader`

Rtsp Stream Details ( from vlc )

[image: stream_details]

this stream plays fine in vlc and `cv::VideoCapture` but when i try to play it in `cudacodec::VideoReader`  i get a **error** saying:

`OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (CUDA_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND [Code = 301]) in CuvidVideoSource, file /home/deep/Development/libraries/opencv/opencv/modules/cudacodec/src/cuvid_video_source.cpp, line 66`

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (init_MediaStream_FFMPEG()) in FFmpegVideoSource, file /home/deep/Development/libraries/opencv/opencv/modules/cudacodec/src/ffmpeg_video_source.cpp, line 101`

**Steps to reproduce**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"

#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_CUDACODEC)

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudacodec.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const std::string fname = "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.13/media/video2";

    cv::namedWindow("GPU", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_frame;
    cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoReader> d_reader = cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(fname);

    for (;;)
    {

        if (!d_reader->nextFrame(d_frame))
            break;

        cv::Mat frame;
        d_frame.download(frame);
        cv::imshow("GPU", frame);

        if (cv::waitKey(3) > 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

#else
int main()
{
    std::cout << "OpenCV was built without CUDA Video decoding support\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

I tried debugging it using GDB and saw that in `ffmpeg_video_source.cpp` `bool init_MediaStream_FFMPEG()` directly returns without checking the if condition.

**GDB output**

```
cv::cudacodec::detail::FFmpegVideoSource::FFmpegVideoSource 
(this=0x402a20 <_start>, fname=...) at /home/deep/Development/libraries/opencv/opencv/modules/cudacodec/src/ffmpeg_video_source.cpp:98
98      cv::cudacodec::detail::FFmpegVideoSource::FFmpegVideoSource(const String& fname) :
(gdb) n
99          stream_(0)
(gdb) n
101         CV_Assert( init_MediaStream_FFMPEG() );
(gdb) s
(anonymous namespace)::init_MediaStream_FFMPEG () at /home/deep/Development/libraries/opencv/opencv/modules/cudacodec/src/ffmpeg_video_source.cpp:94
94              return initialized;
(gdb) display initialized
4: initialized = false
(gdb) s
95          }
```

**UPDATE:**

I have solved the problem. [solution link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9739)

Answer (score 1):

In the solution provided [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9739) the problem was related to the pixel format detected by ffmpeg.

In order to check your rtsp pixel format you can use [ffprobe](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html).
Then inside your [cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/7267e94be78b3c8be4f1f08b912ab57a52cf0954/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L2569) you should add the case related to your pixel format like

```
case AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P:
case AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P:
    *chroma_format = ::VideoChromaFormat_YUV420;
     break;
```

And then rebuild opencv.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Andre yes i solved it. The post you linked is actually mine, i forgot to update the solution here on stackoverflow.